# Simple MySql join in Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I have these three tables and their columns:

```
users
     id   first_name  ...

reports
     id   user_id     title ...

entries
     id   report_id   value
```

this query gives me what I want, which is all entries of an specific user:

```
SELECT entries.value from entries JOIN 
reports ON (entries.report_id = reports.id) where reports.user_id = 2
```

How can I have this using Laravel's eloquent ORM?

Edit:

I have these Models:

```
class User extends \Eloquent
{
    public function reports() {
        return $this->hasMany('Report');
    }
}


class Report extends \Eloquent
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function entries() {
        return $this->hasMany('Entry');
    }
}


class Entry extends \Eloquent
{
    public function report() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Report');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In so far as how to do this in Eloquent (without relationships, since that wasn't included in the original question):

```
Entries::join('reports', 'entries.report_id', '=', 'reports.id')
    ->where('reports.user_id', '=', 2)
    ->select('entries.value');
```

Comment: Apparently we don't have such functionality in Eloquent at this time, and so, yes we have to use the simple query builder approach.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in eloquent at first you have to define relationship among the models(users, reports, entries). Then if you make query for entries and you will find all entity object related to that model.
See how to make relationship from here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I've added my models to the question, do you mean these hasMany, ... that I already have?

Comment: Yes, then it is done already! have you dump your entries you get from query. The entries object should contain its all related object. for example, if $entry is an object entries model then you should have your user & and report object $entry.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do `$user = User::find(2);` then `$user->reports` ... But ... something like ... `$user->reports->entries;` does not work...

Comment: you see your report has many entry so here `$user->reports->entries` is not an single object of entries but an array of object. You can access each object using loop. like `foreach($user->reports->entries as $entry)` and inside this loop you can manipulate $entry as an object as you want.

Comment: In this way I'll have about 40 `SELECT` queries while a single query gives the same result using `JOIN`, Of course that's why I asked a question about `JOIN` in eloquent!

Comment: actually this is not making query again and again. Eleqouent made one query and get all object/entity related to that query. What you have to do is just accessing. you see `$user->reports->entries` is not a query just accessing an array of object

Comment: Oh, that's not how eloquent dynamic properties work! The queries are made and run, when you use each property. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties

Comment: So, is it telling that eloquent run query each time you access any relationship?